# Proof graph theory verification

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification

So, I have to proof the following statement is true for all multigraphs. "Let $\mathscr{G}$ be a multigraph, if the removal of $n$ vertices results in $m > n$ connected components, than $\mathscr{G}$ is not a Hamiltongraph."

We have the following lemma, let's call it Lemma 1: "If you remove $n$ vertices from a Hamiltongraph $\mathscr{K}$ together with the adjacent edges, than $\mathscr{G}$ falls apart in at most $n$ connected components." I think that the contraposition of the lemma I need to proof is exactly Lemma 1 and I know the proof of Lemma 1. Do you think I can use this strategy?

Comment: Yes, you can use the proof of Lemma 1, because it is equivalent to the statement